# Odometry to path rviz

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, rviz, path

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I have a node that publish a message nav_msgs/Odometry, and i want see the trajectory in rviz, i know that i need a nav_msgs/Path. Somebody know a node that do it?

I create a node

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
import rospy
from tf.transformations import quaternion_from_euler
from std_msgs.msg import String
from nav_msgs.msg import Odometry, Path
from geometry_msgs.msg import PoseWithCovarianceStamped, PoseStamped
from sensor_msgs.msg import Joy

import sys
import json
from math import sqrt
from collections import deque

import time


def callback(data):
        global xAnt
        global yAnt
        global cont

    #Is created the pose msg, its necessary do it each time because Python manages objects by reference, 
        #and does not make deep copies unless explicitly asked to do so.
        pose = PoseStamped()    

    #Set a atributes of the msg
        pose.header.frame_id = "odom"
        pose.pose.position.x = float(data.pose.pose.position.x)
        pose.pose.position.y = float(data.pose.pose.position.y)
        pose.pose.orientation.x = float(data.pose.pose.orientation.x)
        pose.pose.orientation.y = float(data.pose.pose.orientation.y)
        pose.pose.orientation.z = float(data.pose.pose.orientation.z)
        pose.pose.orientation.w = float(data.pose.pose.orientation.w)
        
    #To avoid repeating the values, it is found that the received values are differents
        if (xAnt != pose.pose.position.x and yAnt != pose.pose.position.y):
                #Set a atributes of the msg
                pose.header.seq = path.header.seq + 1
                path.header.frame_id="odom"
                path.header.stamp=rospy.Time.now()
                pose.header.stamp = path.header.stamp
                path.poses.append(pose)
                #Published the msg
                
        cont=cont+1

        rospy.loginfo("Valor del contador: %i" % cont)
                if cont>max_append:
                        path.poses.pop(0)
                        
        pub.publish(path)

    #Save the last position
        xAnt=pose.pose.orientation.x
        yAnt=pose.pose.position.y
        return path

    
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
        #Variable initialization
        global xAnt
        global yAnt
        global cont
        xAnt=0.0
        yAnt=0.0
        cont=0

 

        #Node and msg initialization
        rospy.init_node('path_plotter')

        
        #Rosparams that are set in the launch
        #max size of array pose msg from the path
        if not rospy.has_param("~max_list_append"):
                rospy.logwarn('The parameter max_list_append dont exists')
        max_append = rospy.set_param("~max_list_append",1000) 
        max_append = 1000
        if not (max_append > 0):
                rospy.logwarn('The parameter max_list_append not is correct')
                sys.exit()
        pub = rospy.Publisher('/path', Path, queue_size=1)


        path = Path() #creamos el mensaje path de tipo path 
        msg = Odometry()

        #Subscription to the topic
        msg = rospy.Subscriber('/odometry', Odometry, callback) 

        rate = rospy.Rate(30) # 30hz

    try:
                while not rospy.is_shutdown():
                    #rospy.spin()
                    rate.sleep()
        except rospy.ROSInterruptException:
                pass
```

I fixed the bugs and now the code works succesfull. Regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/209580/odometry-to-path-rviz/) by [Porti77](https://answers.ros.org/users/21654/porti77/) on ROS Answers with karma: 183 on 2015-05-20

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ngoldfarb](https://answers.ros.org/users/23280/ngoldfarb/) on 2016-01-13**:
Did you get this working I am having a similar issue

**Comment by [Porti77](https://answers.ros.org/users/21654/porti77/) on 2016-01-14**:
I updated the correct code above.

**Comment by [Porti77](https://answers.ros.org/users/21654/porti77/) on 2016-01-21**:
My answer helped you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can probably use one of the packages in the answers to [show robot trajectory in rviz real-time](http://answers.ros.org/question/209224/show-robot-trajectory-in-rviz-real-time/).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0